# Shapes and colors are not appearing in my JPanel

Tags: java

So whenever I run the application the frame is there however all the colors and rectangles are not. I'm making 3 different menus each intractable so I need 3 panels within my frame. So Ive already taken into account all basic errors so what am I missing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrogVibes");
        JPanel application = new Application();
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel upgradePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel frogPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        mainPanel.setSize(400,690);
        upgradePanel.setSize(400,690);
        frogPanel.setSize(400,690);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        upgradePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frogPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        container.add(mainPanel);
        container.add(upgradePanel);
        container.add(frogPanel);
        frame.add(application);

        new Application() {
        };



        frame.setContentPane(new Container());
        frame.setSize(1280,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0,700,400,100);
        g.drawRect(0, 600,100,150);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Quit posting a question multiple times. That will get you loess help, not more. All the information should be in one place so everybody knows what has been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have just a miss typos, you need to add `container` that you created to the `frame` like so `frame.setContentPane(container);` instead of adding a new container. and I just change colors so that you can see each panel :

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

public class Application extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrogVibes");
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel upgradePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel frogPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("button!");

        mainPanel.setSize(400,200);
        upgradePanel.setSize(500,690);
        frogPanel.setSize(400,690);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        upgradePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frogPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        
        upgradePanel.add(button);

        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        container.add(mainPanel);
        container.add(upgradePanel);
        container.add(frogPanel);

        new Application() {
        };

        frame.setContentPane(container);
        frame.setSize(1280,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

}

public void Graphics(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(0,700,400,100);
    g.drawRect(0, 600,100,150);
}
}
```

and I did already answer you in your last post : [your same previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764439/why-are-my-jpanels-not-showing-color-or-shapes)

Comment: Thank you sorry for posting 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're goal is but you are doing several things incorrectly.  Check out these modifications.

- Use set setPreferredSize() over setSize() since the parent has a layout manager.
- I added the subpanels to your inherited panel (i.e. Application).
- added the Application panel to frame.
- removed contentPane stuff.  JFrame already has a contentPane via frame.add().
- Set colors on some of your panels

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Application extends JPanel{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrogVibes");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Application();
    }
    public Application() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel upgradePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel frogPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        upgradePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        frogPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        upgradePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frogPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        frame.add(this);
        add(mainPanel);
        add(frogPanel);
        add(upgradePanel);
        add(button);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,700));
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0,700,400,100);
        g.drawRect(0, 600,100,150);
    }
}
```

I had to reduce the size of your rectangles.  Also check out Painting in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: much appreciated I don't really know what I'm doing

Comment: I added some colors.  Try it now.